# Count files in a directory by extension

Tags: shell-script, filenames

For the purpose of testing, I'd like count how many images files are inside a directory, separating each image file type by file extension (jpg="yes". This because later it will be useful for another script that will execute an action on each file extension). Can I use something like the following for only JPEG files?

```
jpg=""
count=`ls -1 *.jpg 2>/dev/null | wc -l`
if [ $count != 0 ]
then
echo jpg files found: $count ; jpg="yes"
fi
```

Considering file extensions jpg, png, bmp, raw and others, should I use a `while` cycle to do this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'd suggest a different approach, avoiding the possible word-splitting issues of `ls`

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s nullglob

for ext in jpg png gif; do 
  files=( *."$ext" )
  printf 'number of %s files: %d\n' "$ext" "${#files[@]}"

  # now we can loop over all the files having the current extension
  for f in "${files[@]}"; do
    # anything else you like with these files
    :
  done 

done
```

You can loop over the `files` array with any other commands you want to perform on the files of each particular extension.

---

More portably - or for shells that don't provide arrays explicitly - you could re-use the shell's positional parameter array i.e.

```
set -- *."$ext"
```

and then replace `${#files[@]}` and `${files[@]}` with `$#` and `"$@"`

Answer (score 32):

My approach would be:

1. List all files in the directory
2. Extract their extension
3. Sort the result
4. Count the occurrences of each extension

Sort of like this (last `awk` call is purely for formatting):

```
ls -q -U | awk -F . '{print $NF}' | sort | uniq -c | awk '{print $2,$1}'
```

(assuming GNU `ls` here for the `-U` option to skip sorting as an optimisation. It can be safely removed without affecting functionality if not supported).

Comment: mhmh... later should I filter each extension found for do an action for it?

Comment: It depends on what you want to do in the end. Can you give more information?

Comment: My goal: a script that process each extension file (only image file) changing the size from input user data. So, I start from how many jpg files there're, next png, etc.

Comment: steeldrivers solution may be more appropriate then.

Comment: I had both `JPG` and `jpg` files, and wanted it recursively so my solution was to write `find . -type f | awk -F . '{print tolower($NF)}' | sort | uniq -c | awk '{print $2,":",$1}'`

Comment: Replace `ls` with `ls -U` for high performance. (`ls` sorts output by default. By turning off sorting with option `-U` you'd make execution much faster.)

Answer (score 20):

This recursively traverses files and counts extensions that match:

```
$ find . -type f | sed -e 's/.*\.//' | sort | uniq -c | sort -n | grep -Ei '(tiff|bmp|jpeg|jpg|png|gif)$'
   6 tiff
   7 bmp
  26 jpeg
  38 gif
  51 jpg
  54 png
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thanks a lot! Needed something that could quickly run on the CLI.

Answer (score 9):

```
find -type f | sed -e 's/.*\.//' | sort | uniq -c
```

Comment: Don't forget a starting directory with `find`. Also, it can help future readers of these answers if you give a brief explanation of your solution (in case they would like to modify it for a slightly different case).

Comment: How well does this solution deal with path names containing spaces? Newlines?

Comment: `find` defaults to the current directory, which is how I use this. I don't think God intended filenames to have spaces in them, but this works fine for that case. If you have newlines, then you deserve all you get. I thought about an explanation but decided it would make the answer too long, I think simplicity is what matters. 99% of the cases in 1% of the time. This is probably Version 7 compatible.

Answer (score 3):

Anything involving `ls` is likely to produce unexpected results with special chars (space and other symbols). Any bashism (like arrays) isn't portable. Anything involving `while read` is usually slow.

On the other hand, `find` is VERY flexible (lots of options to filter), it has [at least] two syntax which are fail safe for special chars... and It scales well on large directory.

For this example, I have used `-iname` to match both upper and lower case extension name. I have also restricted the `-maxdepth 1` to respect your question's "in current directory". Rather than counting the number of lines, where filenames could include CR/LF, `-print0` will print a NULL byte at the end of each filename... so `| tr -d -c "\000" | wc -l` is accurately counting files (NULL bytes!).

```
extensions="jpg png gif"
for ext in $extensions; do
  c=$(find . -maxdepth 1 -iname "*.$ext" -print0 | tr -d -c "\000" | wc -c)
  if [ $c -gt 0 ]; then
    echo "Found $c  *.$ext files"

    find . -maxdepth 1 -iname "*.$ext" -print0 | xargs -0 -r -n1 DOSOMETHINGHERE
    # or #  find . -maxdepth 1 -iname "*.$ext" -exec "ls" "-l" "{}" ";"
  fi
done
```

P.S. `-print0 | tr -d -c "\000" | wc -c` can be replaced with `-printf "\000" | wc -c` or even `-printf '\n' | wc -l`.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it can get shorter

```
exts=( *.jpg *.png *.gif ); printf "There are ${#exts[@]}" extensions;
```

Answer (score 1):

can just use ls for something this simple IMO

```
ls -l /opt/ssl/certs/*.pem | wc -l
```

or

```
count=$(ls -l /some/folder/*.jpg | wc -l)
```

or

```
ls *.{mp3,exe,mp4} 2>/dev/null | wc -l
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually this type of task is best solved by breaking it up into chunks (the [Unix philosophy](https://homepage.cs.uri.edu/~thenry/resources/unix_art/ch01s06.html)). Find the files, strip out all but their extensions, sort alphabetically (to break ties) then by number of occurrences:

```
find . -type f | egrep -o '\.[^/.]+$' | sort | uniq -c | sort -n
```

You might like additional flourishes. I removed files which are only extension (like .gitignore), combined results by case (so gif and GIF are both under gif), and stripped out the initial dot:

```
find . -type f | egrep -v '^\.' | egrep -o '\.[^/.]+$' | tr 'A-Z' 'a-z' | sed -e 's/^\.//' | sort | uniq -c | sort -n
```

You might instead choose to limit to certain image types

```
find . -type f -iname '*.jpg' -o -iname '*.jpeg' -o -iname '*.png' -o -iname '*.bmp' -o -iname '*.raw' -o -iname '*.gif' | egrep -o '\.[^.]+$' | uniq -c | sort -n
```

Hopefully these are both useable of themselves and show how to combine the various utilities into a nice result.

Answer (score -1):

If you are sure of the extension, you can go with `find` like

```
find *.jpeg | wc -l
```

Comment: until someone creates `touch $'foo\nbar.jpeg` and it gets counted twice instead of once. Or worse, someone does `mkdir directory.jpeg; touch directory.jpeg/{1..100}.txt`

Comment: `find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.jpeg' | wc -l`