# Bash script to check for file extentions in directory

Tags: bash, shell-script

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
#Number for .txt files
txtnum=0
#Number of .sh files
shnum=0

for file in "SOME_PATH";do
  #if file has extension .txt
   if [[ $file ==* ".txt"]]
   then 
    #increment the number of .txt files (txtnum)
    txtnum++
   elif [[ $file ==* ".sh"]]
   then 
    #increment the number of .sh files (shnum)
    shnum++
   fi
echo "Number of files with .txt extension:$txtnum"
echo "Number of files with .sh extension:$shnum"
```

The above code does not work, but it presents the logic I want it to have.

New to `bash`, commands might not be right either.

Comment: Thanks for the edit,new to the site,don't know how it works.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Could you please indicate in what way the code does not work? Do you get a specific error message? Can you show us actual console output, and compare it to desired output? If so, please edit your post to include that information; it will make it easier for contributors to help you track down the problem.

Comment: No,the code I wrote is on my phone,and I can't test it . Also i'm quite new to bash,but I understand programming logic,so the code I wrote is code that I'm not sure it works,but I know what logic I want it to have.I don't have my PC with me,but I want to create a working code when I get home.

Comment: ls -1 SOME_PATH/*.txt | wc -l

Comment: For simpler and more robust ways to do this, you might want to take a look at [Count files in a directory by extension](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/146760/count-files-in-a-directory-by-extension)

Comment: You can check syntax with https://shellcheck.net

Answer (score 2):

Since it's been redacted I can't say for sure but `SOME_PATH` would have to include an unquotted glob `*` to expand to the files in the directory.  Something like:

`/path/to/*`

Next `[[ $file ==* ".txt"]]` is not valid, specifically `==*` is not a valid comparison operator.  You could use `=~` to perform regex comparison like `[[ $file =~ .*\.txt ]]`, but personally I would extract the extension first and compare that individually.

Next `shnum++` is not valid, you would need to perform that inside of a shell arithmetic `((` compound command, such as: `((shnum++))`

Finally you are missing a closing `done` statement for your `for` loop.

---

Here is some working code that will accomplish what you need:

```
#!/bin/bash

txtnum=0
shnum=0

for file in /path/to/files/*; do
    ext="${file##*.}"
    if [[ $ext == txt ]]; then
        ((txtnum++))
    elif [[ $ext == sh ]]; then
        ((shnum++))
    fi
done

printf 'Number of .txt files: %d\n' "$txtnum"
printf 'Number of .sh files: %d\n' "$shnum"
```

Comment: Thank you,got to test it when I go home,but it looks like exactly what I need!

Comment: Just tested it,worked exactly how  I wanted it to. Thank you!

Comment: This isn't quite right, because if a filename doesn't contain ".", it'll treat the entire thing as the extension. I'd use tests like `if [[ $file == *.txt ]]; then` instead -- bash treats the right side of `=` (or `==`) in a `[[ ]]` conditional expression as a glob pattern (unless it's quoted), so the wildcard will do what it looks like.

Comment: If the filename doesn't contain a `.` it will not match so there is no issue.

Comment: Alternatively, using an associative array: `(( ext_count[$ext]++ ))`

Answer (score 1):

You can generalise this requirement to count as many extensions as you need. For this you will need a shell that supports associative arrays, such as `bash`.

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -A exts

for path in "${SOME_PATH-.}"/*
do
    # Only files
    [[ -f "$path" ]] || continue

    # Split off the file component, and then its name and extension
    file=${path##*/}
    name=${file%.*} extn=${file##*.}
    # printf "%s -> %s -> %s %s\n" "$path" "$file" "$name" "$extn"

    # Count this extension type
    (( exts[$extn]++ ))
done

# Here is what we want to know
echo "txt=${exts[txt]-0}, sh=${exts[sh]-0}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
#!/bin/bash
txtnum=0
shnum=0

for file in /some/dir/*;do
  if [[ "${file}" =~ \.txt$ ]];then
    txtnum=$((txtnum+1))
  elif [[ "${file}" =~ \.sh$ ]];then
    shnum=$((shnum+1))
  fi
done

echo "Number of files with .txt extention:${txtnum}"
echo "Number of files with .sh extention:${shnum}"
```

Answer (score 0):

One method is to use find(1) and count the number of finds wc(1).

One method to deal with filenames which troublesome characters (newline/space etc) is to have find output for example the i-node number.

```
#!/bin/bash

txtnum=0
shnum=0
directory=/tmp/somewhere


txtnum=$(/bin/find ${directory} -maxdepth 1 -name '*.txt' -type f -printf "%i\n"|/bin/wc -l)
shnum=$(/bin/find ${directory}  -maxdepth 1 -name '*.sh'  -type f -printf "%i\n"|/bin/wc -l)

echo "Number of .txt files: ${txtnum}"
echo "Number of .sh files: ${shnum}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't loop if you don't have to.  Don't loop in the shell unless you're *operating* on the files.

For a large number of filenames, this will work faster than any other solution proposed thus far:

```
$ ls /usr/lib | awk -F '[/.]+' \
  '{ ext[$NF]++ } END { for(e in ext){ printf ".%-7s\t%4d\n", e, ext[e]} }' | 
grep -Ew 'so|0' # or extensions of your choice
.0                28
.so               10
```

Less typing, too!